# Need info on the commands used by ios_facts module

Tags: ansible

We plan to do IOS upgrade and I am using `ios_facts` module to compare/manipulate info.

There is a team to which we have given limited access to network devices and need to know what command does `ios_facts` module execute on Cisco devices to gather the info that it does? So we will give access to these commands to that team so that the script would work when this team runs the script using their id.

I went through several Ansible documentation for network modules, but the exact commands executed by `ios_facts` is not mentioned anywhere. Some documentation give an idea on what type of info is gathered but the exact command is not given. Since same info can be gathered using multiple commands in Cisco devices sometimes, so it is difficult to make a guess.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding your question

> What command does `ios_facts` module execute on Cisco devices to gather the info that it does?

and according the source of [ios_facts.py](https://github.com/ansible-collections/cisco.ios/blob/main/plugins/modules/ios_facts.py) you may find parts of the answer under [plugins/module_utils/network/ios/facts](https://github.com/ansible-collections/cisco.ios/tree/main/plugins/module_utils/network/ios/facts).

Please take note that it is [according documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/cisco/ios/ios_facts_module.html#examples) possible to control `gather_facts` with `gather_subset` and some filters like `hardware`, `interfaces`, `config` and more. See [facts.py](https://github.com/ansible-collections/cisco.ios/blob/main/plugins/module_utils/network/ios/facts/facts.py)

```
 91 FACT_LEGACY_SUBSETS = dict(
 92     default=Default, hardware=Hardware, interfaces=Interfaces, config=Config
 93 )
 94 
 95 FACT_RESOURCE_SUBSETS = dict(
    ...
117 )
```

Therefore it will depend on you which parts you will access.

In example if the subset would be interfaces only, the command is then according [interfaces.py](https://github.com/ansible-collections/cisco.ios/blob/main/plugins/module_utils/network/ios/facts/interfaces/interfaces.py)

```
50 def get_interfaces_data(self, connection):
51    return connection.get("sh running-config | section ^interface")
```

> I went through several ansible documentation ...

Since we have almost all parts open source here we can luckily just browse the code. There is also a search function which can just lookup all appearances of [`return connection.get(`](https://github.com/ansible-collections/cisco.ios/search?q=%22return+connection.get%28%22).

Comment: Thanks for the links. I am gethering ios_facts with subset 'all'.  You have mentioned that parts of the answer can be found in above link.  Would you be able to give any pointers on where i may be able to get complete info?    Also in the last link you shared, it seems to show 'show' commands used by ios_facts and we have already given access to all 'show' commands to this team yet script fails. So iam guessing thered may be some other command involved.